# Android : Created System Notification. - Can you retrieve parameters on notification CLICK?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I've created a notification.  When the user clicks the notification within the android operating system, it successfully starts the desired activity.  It calls the OnCreate on my Activity_Send.class.  My question is, can i access any information regarding that notification?  The title of the notification, or the ID or is it even possible to pass parameters that I can set when creating the notification that i can retrieve when it calls my activity??

The below code is what im using to create my notification...
REVISED CODE

```
private static void notice(String msgfrom, String msg) {
Intent intent = null;
    String title;

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(appctx);

title = "New message from " + msgfrom;
SendUser = msgfrom;     // Who we sending message to?
intent = new Intent( appctx, Activity_Send.class);  
intent.putExtra("from", msgfrom);
intent.putExtra("id",Integer.toString(NoticeCount));
if (whoscreen != null) { stackBuilder.addNextIntent(whoscreen); }
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

//PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(appctx,NoticeCount,intent, 0);
PendingIntent pintent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(NoticeCount, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder nb =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(appctx);
nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pp);
    nb.setContentTitle(title);
nb.setContentText(modmsg);
nb.setAutoCancel(true);
nb.setContentIntent(pintent);


    Notification notification = nb.build();
    NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) appctx.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NM.notify(NoticeCount, notification);   
    NoticeCount = NoticeCount +1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put anything you want in the `Intent` that is used to start your `Activity_Send` class as **extras**. For example:

```
intent.putExtra("notificationTitle", title);
intent.putExtra("notificationId", NoticeCount);
```

You haven't posted the code you use to create `pintent`, but it should look something like:

```
pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

This `PendingIntent` is then set on the `Notification` using `setContentIntent()`.

In `onCreate()` of `Activity_Send` you can get the extras back like this:

```
String notificationTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra("notificationTitle");
int notificationId = getIntent().getIntExtra("notificationId", -1);
```

Comment: Awesome!  So much appreciate your response!!!!  Worked PERFECTLY!!!  Maybe i wasn't using the correct key search words, but i spent over an hour trying to find the answer in stackoverflow to no avail.  Thanks again!

Comment: David, we have a problem.  I found a scenario where this fails on me.  If i receive one notification, and click on that notification, it works just fine.  But, if i receive two different notifications, then the getIntent().getStringExtra returns null on both notifications when clicked.  Ps, here is the line i was using regarding the pending intent.  

PendingIntent pintent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: I changed the pendingintent to the line you gave and the result it a bit different.  Now, instead of null, clicking on either notification returns the latest GetString extra of the last notification.  As if the first one was overwritten.

Comment: If you need to have more than one of these available at the same time, you need to make sure that you create a unique `PendingIntent` each time. To do this, use a unique ID as the second parameter of `PendingIntent.getActivity()`. This will ensure that it creates a different `PendingIntent` each time.

Comment: If you require the task stack builder, you should also be able to use `stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(x, 0)` where `x` is a unique ID for each notification.

Comment: That did it! -- I will see if that also does it with the StackBuilder.  Appreciate the help.  Enjoy your weekend.

Comment: Okay, i modified the question to show the full code. I can toggle quickly between the two methods by commenting one or the other where setting the pintent.  When i use the stackbuilder method, I get a null on one or both when calling : `SendUser = getIntent().getStringExtra("from");`  Any thoughts?  Do i need to use another method within the OnCreate to grab the information?

Comment: Are you using the backwards-compatibility library or the real stuff (for `TaskStackBuilder`)? And what version of Android are you testing this on?

Comment: `Android 2.33` and im importing import `android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;` if that answers your questions...